# Recommended WOL-Compatible LAN Card/Chipset?

Tags: networking, drivers, wakeup, wakeonlan

So I have a built-in LAN Card with a Realtek 8111 Chipset. As some of you may know, this is a major pain to get WOL working on.

I have had no luck trying everything under the sun to try to get it to work from my Pi on the same LAN.

So I've decided to simply buy a new PCI LAN Card seeing as they're not super expensive. Now unfortunately I can't find any info online as to what works and what doesn't with Ubuntu.

Does anyone have any experience with a specific card or chipset that worked well?

Comment: Ah okay, just wanted to put the info on here in case someone else stumbles upon this thread with similar issues / motherboard config options.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about hardware recommendation.

Comment: OP here. Do whatever you want with it - the issue has been resolved, I just thought my successful resolution of the problem could possibly help others who may stumble upon this thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wanted to post the solution in case anyone else stumbles upon this thread.

I fixed it by setting my BIOS Settings to the following:

ACPI suspend state: [from S1] to S3.

That seemed to clear it up.

So maybe the LAN Card/Chipset was being unnecessarily shutdown where I didnt want it to be.

Anyway it works now :)